# How would I write the interface for an object that renders itself while allowing easy unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

As an example here, I've got an `LockedCrateObject` in a game engine. It can be locked using a key, which is functionality I want to write a unit test for. It also is responsible for drawing itself though that functionality will never be used in the unit test. The following is how I would implement it without a unit test in mind:

```
class LockedCrateObject : IWorldObject
{
    IGraphics m_Graphics;

    public Inventory Inventory;
    public KeySlot KeySlot;

    public LockedCrateObject(IGraphics graphics)
    {
        m_Graphics = graphics;

        /* Add some data to Inventory and KeySlot and
           bind OnValidKey and OnEndValidKey to KeySlot's Events */
    }

    void OnValidKey()
    {
        Inventory.Locked = false;
    }

    void OnEndValidKey()
    {
        Inventory.Locked = true;
    }

    public void Draw() { /* Use m_Graphics to render the crate */ }
}
```

This would require the unit test to supply an implementation of `IGraphics` even though it would never be used during the unit test. I could pass it to Draw directly but that would mean every single class that needs to render something in the entire engine needs to start juggling references around every frame rather than the reference being passed around once. I'm concerned that that would have an impact on performance. I could also allow null to be passed to the constructor but that would mean someone could by mistake assume the object will work fine without it, resulting in a null pointer exception.

How should I redesign this class to allow easy unit testing of the crate locking without having to create an entire mock object implementing `IGraphics`?

Comment: It would depend on what "success" meant for drawing of this object.  You could pass a mock IGraphics in then validate that some method got called after Draw; but what specific method would depend on what IGraphics allows.  Plus, is such a method called on IGraphics mean that LockedCreateObject was drawn correctly?

Comment: It will draw itself using OpenGL calls. Making sure drawing is done correctly is way too complex for to test in the unit tests and I don't want to make opengl calls in the unit test.

Comment: So, create an IGraphics "spy" implementation that keeps track of what method is called and verify that method was called in the unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One argument would be: separation of concerns would suggest that your rendering and behavioural code should live in separate classes. However, I know how hard that can be to implement in some games engines.

So, as an alternative to not "having to create an entire mock object implementing `IGraphics`", how about "easily create that mock?"

For example, using [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/), it could be this simple:

```
var mockGraphics = new Mock<IGraphics>();
var target = new LockedCrateObject(mockGraphics.Object);
```

Since you aren't unit testing the methods that require the `IGraphics` object, it doesn't matter that the mock's behaviour isn't fleshed out.

Comment: I am here early on in the design progress. No code has been written yet so I do have the option to separate concerns. Though I assumed that would in this case be that an object like this calls a function in a rendering helper class. How would you suggest separating concerns for this class?

Comment: Well, obviously I can't see your wider codebase, but an "object in the world" might have a number of separate bits of behaviour - it might be represented as a *number* of classes rather than just one. Or, perhaps, each `IWorldObject` could have a property of type `Renderer` that in turn has `.Model`, `.Texture` and `.Draw()` - and can then be tested separately.

Comment: In fact, the Unity3d engine pretty much follows this model: each "GameObject" has a number of "Components" and each component implements a specific behaviour.

Comment: So then the idea is to have the LockedCrateObject internally maintain a separate LockedCrateRenderer and LockedCrateBehavior with the locking behavior being part of the Behavior class while the rendering is part of the Renderer? This way I could separately test behavior and rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know everything that your IGraphics interface needs to do; so, assuming it has a "draw" operation, you could create a *spy* implementation like this:

```
public class GraphicsSpy : IGraphics
{
    public void Draw()
    {
        DrawCalled = true;
    }
    public bool DrawCalled{get;private set;}
}
```

Then, use that in your unit test (depending on your test framework):

```
[Test]
public void LockedCrateObjectIsDrawnCorrectly()
{
    var graphicsSpy = new GraphicsSpy();
    var lockedCrateObject = new LockedCrateObject(graphicsSpy);
    lockedCrateObject.Draw();
    Assert.IsTrue(graphicsSpy.DrawCalled);
}
```

Comment: While initially I thought this would be overkill testing, I'll definitely be going with this since requirements of game objects are that they're always visible.